# Django post not showing on homepage, but in category list

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I made a blog with Django. The blog lets the admin create posts and categories. I used bootstrap to align the posts next to each other.
This is the homepage of my blog. When the posts reach the other end of the screen. look at the Example below:

post1    post2   post3   post4   post5   post6   post7   post8   post9   post10 post11 post12 post 13  post14 post16.

`post 16` wouldnot show on the homepage, but if you go to its category it will show on the category list but not on the homepage which is index.html

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if categories %}
<div class="tab">
{% for category in categories %}
<button class="tablinks"><a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ 
category.title }}</a></button>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<p>There are no posts.</p>
{% endif %}

</div>
<br><br><br>
<div class="container ">
{% if posts %}
<div class="row ">
{% for post in posts %}
 <div class="poosts col-md-2">
 <p class="past"><a class="link" href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><span 
class="tda"> {{post.title}}</span><br><br><span class="postbody">
{{post.body|truncatewords:13}}</a></span></p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %} 

{% else %}
    <p class="text-center">There are no posts.</p>
</div>
{% endif %}


</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**categories page**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head_title %}Viewing category {{ category.title }}{% endblock %}
{% block title %}{{ category.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<br><br><br>
<div class="container">
{% if posts %}
<div class="row">
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="poosts col-md-4">

<p class="past"><a class="link" href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><span 
class="tda"> {{post.title}}</span><br><br>{{post.body|truncatewords:13}}</a>
</p>
</div>
{% endfor %} 

{% else %}
<p class="text-center">There are no posts.</p>
</div>
{% endif %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_list_or_404
from django.http import  HttpResponse
from .models import Blog, Category
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404


def index(request):
     return render_to_response('account/index.html', {
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
        'posts': Blog.objects.all()[:5]
     })

def view_post(request, slug):

    return render_to_response('account/view_post.html', {
           'post': get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug)
    })

def view_category(request, slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    return render_to_response('account/view_category.html', {
           'category': category,
           'posts': Blog.objects.filter(category=category)[:5]
    })
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import permalink

class Blog(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
      slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
      body = models.TextField()
      posted = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
      category = models.ForeignKey('Category')

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % self.title

@permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('view_blog_post', None, { 'slug': self.slug })


def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Category(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
      slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % self.title


@permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('view_blog_category', None, { 'slug': self.slug })

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: try printing `Category.objects.all()` in index and respond with output

Comment: On the homepage it only shows 5 posts

Comment: do you mean in the views.py and can what to you mean respond with output

Comment: @Nawaf You are limiting it to 5 posts with `Blog.objects.all()[:5]`.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this 'posts': `Blog.objects.all()` in views.py